# Configure H2 database for testing Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to make tests with embedded database and I want to check results in h2-console. I have configured properties for tests and I want to store my test data to have a look on it, but it always writes *Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version* and uses another h2 DB like "jdbc:h2:mem:1f4af8a8-3e14-4755-bcbd-5a59aa31033e". What can I do with this problem?
"application-test.properties":

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./subdirectory/demodb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

My test class:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ProductRepositoryTest {
    @Test
    void findByProductName() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53803780/6572971 might help.

Comment: if you use this test method into a controller, result is same ?

Comment: Already tried it. Didn't help( .properties are not working

Comment: I have tried it only with Repository. Didn't try with controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `@DataJpaTest` annotation replaces your production DB with an embedded one, wraps every test method in a transaction and rolls it back at the end of the test.

If you want to run your test as if it was a "real" operation on the DB, you can add the following annotations to your test class:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

The first one tells Spring not to use the embedded DB, while the second one tells it to work non-transactionally (every query will be persisted).

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found to prevent the replacement of the datasource with an embedded one is to add the following Spring property:

```
spring.test.database.replace: none
```

This might be more convenient if you have a lot of classes annotated with `@DataJpaTest`.